# React Native - Multiple iOS builds per project

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

**Scenario**

I have two apps that are identical except for some minor textual differences. Currently I have 2x projects and would like to condense them into one.

eg.

```
      React Native Project
          /         \
Xcode build 1      Xcode build 2
```

Another important caveat: App Signatures

I assume the App Stores recognize app uploads by some sort of archive/compilation signature, not by app name. This is why I'm wanting to do 2 separate xcode builds rather than 1 xcode build.

**Question**

Can a React Native project maintain 2 separate Xcode builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running multiple builds off of the same application is a pretty common paradigm in iOS development, and this holds true for React Native as well.

The instructions [here](https://www.buddybuild.com/blog/running-multiple-schemes-of-ios-apps) should get you well on the way to configuring multiple builds, with unique bundleIds (what the app store will use to recognize it as a unique application).

To test them out on your machine after configuring everything, you can use the following command as an example.

`react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPhone X' --scheme 'YOUR_SCHEME' --configuration 'YOUR_NEW_CONFIGURATION'`

I would start by just duplicating your Release config and renaming it, just to make sure that it runs fine on your machine before you start playing around with the configuration.